# Copy Result of a Query into another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have selected all tables using this query

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA from information_schema.tables
```

I want to copy the result of this query to another table `info` in its column `table_names`
I want to do this in 1 query. Is this possible?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Please provide sample data to explain what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this,but not tested

```
INSERT INTO info (table_names) SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA FROM information_schema.tables
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Info
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA from information_schema.tables

select * from Info
```

But  SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA from information_schema.tables
 will return dbo, etc, schema names, if you want to get table names use

```
select name from sys.tables
```

so use

```
INSERT INTO Info
SELECT name 
FROM sys.tables
```

See http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLSelectInsert.aspx for example for insert into with select, there're many other samples.

Comment: I don't think that is valid syntax for MySQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I thought insert into select was valid mysql

Comment: Yes, but not the `declare` and not the `@temp` table definition.